# Python: values from csv-list

Tags: python, list, csv, sorting, arraylist

I create a list from a csv-file with the output of the first line:

```
from csv import reader
    
    with open('GAB_Trends_210406/GAB_trendHwsCeilingSupplyTempEast_210406.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = reader(csv_file)
        
        list_of_rows = list(csv_reader)
        print(list_of_rows[0])
```

the output it`s:

```
['28.Mrz 2021 03:46:19 UTC,{ },{ok},485529,,"33,80"']
```

How can I only printout the value "28.Mrz 2021 03:46:19 UTC" and "33,80"?

NEW:

I have now this:

```
row = list_of_rows[0] **#row 0 of list**
timestamp = row[0][:20]
value = row[0][43:48]
print(timestamp + ": " + value)
```

if i change the line to :

```
row = list_of_rows[10] **#row 10 of list**
timestamp = row[0][:20]
value = row[0][43:48]
print(timestamp + ": " + value)
```

How can I do this codeblock for each row of the list? I tried with a for-loop but it don`t worked..

Comment: So you question and the title actually is: __How to print out the first and last column of a CSV file (for first row)__ ?

Answer (score 0):

When you grab list_of_rows[0], you get the row defined as a list. If you want the first and last elements of that list, you have to access them by their index.

```
row = list_of_rows[0]
timestamp = row[0]
finalvalue = row[-1] # Indexes final element
print(timestamp, finalvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to process the first item of a list, this is actually a matter of string manipulation. This can be solved in various ways.

Given the string:

```
d = '28.Mrz 2021 03:46:19 UTC,{ },{ok},485529,,"33,80"'
```

You could split the string and get the required elements:

```
print(d.split(',{')[0], d.split(',,')[-1])
```

Or you could slice the string:

```
print(d[:24], d[-7:])
```

Both will result in the desired output:

```
28.Mrz 2021 03:46:19 UTC "33,80"
```

For your function that would be:

```
print(list_of_rows[0][:24], list_of_rows[0][-7:])
```